# How to wire AprilAire 500

Tags: humidifier

I replaced my AprilAire 500 with a new one of same model. I can’t remember how to connect the yellow wires from the humidifier. I’m uploading a picture of all the wires coming to the circled area where I need help. I never disconnected any of the other wires except where the power source goes to the transformer from the electric outlet but that was black on black and white on white. Right now the humidifier comes on but it isn’t telling the solenoid to let the water in when needed. Please help. [image]

Comment: What make/model is your furnace?

Comment: AprilAire model 500

Comment: Your *furnace*, not your humidifier...

Comment: I found out the problem. I had bought a new humidifier of the same brand and model and put the new solenoid and transformer in place where the old ones were and didn’t notice that the solenoids had different numbers on them. Once I switched it back to the old one it was able to communicate to turn it on. You were right on how the wiring went also. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This is from the manual:
[image]
This is where I stop being much help. The manual uses the accessory port from the furnace to drive the solenoid/power the unit. That being said, per your diagram the furnace most likely offers a switch on heat call for the 'H' terminals. If that is the case, then the wires would be connected like this:
[image]
You will need to verify:

1. that the furnace control board can handle the current needed.
2. That the furnace control board is not supplying power and is just a switch.
3. Your diagram shows turning on the water, but not the blower, so I am assuming the humidifier blower is powered some other way (or there isn't a blower and furnace air is used only.)

Comment: Yes the furnace is the blower. I have a friend coming over today to help so I will have him look at how the furnace is hooked up. Thanks